# HTML / CSS / Javascript - Changing one table cell value, when hovering over a different cell

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, hover

I don't actually have any code relating to this, as it is completely hypothetical, but I was just wondering how simple it would be to do.

Lets say, for example, I have a standard table with 4 cells.

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Cell 1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cell 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cell 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cell 4</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now I want to hover over cell 2 and have an image display in cell 3... Is this possible using JavaScript?

Comment: is jQuery an alternative?

Comment: Of course it is possible in JS. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Could you add a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @howderek it is ridiculously easy to copy that table into jsfiddle.

Comment: @Tyriar, yeah but he may have some js we don't know about.

Comment: Like i said in the question, it's a hypothetical question which could be used in many places, it is as simple as the question states at this point!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to achive that using only css. There are at least two selectros that might be helpful.

First one is `+`, second one is `nth-child()`. So lets say you always want to display the image in table cell n+1, where n is the cell you're hovering:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="yoursource.jpg"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="yoursource2.jpg"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can try it this way:

```
img { display: none; }
tr:hover + tr img { display: block; }
```

Or you can create rule using css3 selectors:

```
img { display: none; }
tr:nth-child(n+1):hover + tr img { display: block; }
```

I guess there are few more ways to do it only by using css, but of course it'll work only if you have images already in your code (you didn't precise if you want to just display them or load them).

[working example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aguyH)

Comment: Hmm this is an interesting slant on the feature which I will also try out and use the most appropriate! Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Give this code a try. Keep in mind that this does **exactly** what you asked, no more, no less. You'll want to extend this code properly using classes (instead of IDs) if you want a maintainable solution, but that would be beyond the scope of this question.

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Cell 1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="hoverover">Cell 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="changeme">Cell 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cell 4</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <script>
            var hoverEl = document.getElementById('hoverover'),
                changeEl = document.getElementById('changeme');

            hoverEl.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
                changeEl.innerHTML = '<img src="/path/to/image" />';
            }, false);
            hoverEl.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
                changeEl.innerHTML = 'Cell 3';
            }, false);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It will destroy the table structure, innerHTML removes table cells. You can move `id` to `td` instead of `tr`.

Comment: Have tried using both, and they both work sufficiently. It will just depend on what circumstance I need to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more generic example with pure JavaScript. It changes the background of the next `td` for all the `td`. For the last one it will change the background of the first. Setting to a background image would be as simple as changing the CSS to use `background-image` instead of `background-color`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/rTuYG/)

**JavaScript**

```
var tds = document.querySelectorAll('td');
for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
    tds[i].onmouseover = (function (i) {
        return function () {
            tds[(i + 1) % tds.length].className = 'hovered';
        }
    })(i);
    tds[i].onmouseout = (function (i) {
        return function () {
            tds[(i + 1) % tds.length].className = '';
        }
    })(i);
}
```

**CSS**

```
.hovered {
    background-color:#F00;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that cracked it. Thank you, will be using this in the future. I'm extremely happy with the amount of support I received after this is my first post on the site!